# Firebase Function - Client IP always Internal to Google

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase Function, specifically for Dialogflow chatbot fulfillment. I am having trouble getting an accurate client IP address regardless of how I am testing it.

I've seen on various posts the various ways to read client IP, but they are either `undefined` or an internal Google IP from one of their data centers.

I've tried reading:

```
"x-forwarded-for" header
req.connection.remoteAddress
req.ip
req.ips (collection of all of them, there is only ever 1 in the collection)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to log analaytics around user interactions, and right now the IPs are all incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following code which is provided [here](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6fffffb45ee5cbfbca6c3511e5d19528):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const util = require('util');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // For Firebase Hosting URIs, use req.headers['fastly-client-ip']
  // For callable functions, use rawRequest
  // Some users have better success with req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']
  const ipAddress = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
  const headers = JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2);
  const message = util.format("<pre>Hello world!\n\nYour IP address: %s\n\nRequest headers: %s</pre>", ipAddress, headers);
  res.send(message);
});
```

When tested (even with mobile data), it returned the public IP of the caller and not a Google Internal IP.

If try this, do you continue getting internal IPs?